# Get part of current_timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I do

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I get `2021-02-02 13:58:44`.

I want take only this part: `13:58:44` and store it in a variable.

Comment: See the manual for all options: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: Cast it to a time: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::time` or use `localtime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5a9e18cb1ea2720c528d69a5d4e688fe)

You can cast a timestamp into type time:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::time
```

Or you can `localtime` directly.